# Sdk location in AOSP

Tags: android, gradle, android-source

Note - I am relatively new to Android and AOSP...

Where can I find the Android SDK in the AOSP? As we know, we build apk files in the android studio using the separately installed SDK. But for some reason, I wish to use the SDK in the AOSP if it is available. I see the source code of SDK in the AOSP; do we need to build it?

Why/How I have arrived at the above question:

1. I had created an .apk in the AOSP which had JNI files and dependency on some existing Broadcom libs (so). It is a system app. What I noticed is the .apk package does not contain the JNI libs but rather is copied to /system/lib folder separately. **Hence I had a doubt how the .apk upgrade will work? Is it possible?**
2. I assumed the .apk upgrade won't work that way and the .apk should be packaged including the JNI libs. Hence I planned to build the .apk in the studio and use the .apk as prebuilt and just sign it in the AOSP (we have the keys). Then I also wanted to allow the developers to build the .apk in AOSP itself by running the Gradle in the command line. I did so by adding the command to the Android.mk. But the point here is, it is still using the SDK installed in /home//Android/Sdk. But there may be build machines which may not have the SDK installed. So I am putting this question - **Do we (where?) have the SDK in AOSP? Can I use that instead?**

I tried to explain the problem.. in case it's not clear please let me know... Will try to give more details...

Answer (score 2):

1. OTA update will work. Update with Package Manager - won't. This is normal for system apps with native libraries.

In AOSP applications are built differently depending on their location in build tree. Apps placed in *~/packages/apps* and *~/device/some_vendor* are system apps and they are handled differently by the system. One of differences is that during build process they are stripped of their native libraries and those libraries are simply copied to the /system/ partition.

2. Including pre-built apk is a good solution. 
   Yes you can build sdk yourself from sources. Yes, it's there. But I don't understand why you need that. Are there any changes to the API?
3. There are other options. For example, you can mangle your build scripts. Say, you can add a global FLAG that would disable lib stripping for system apps.

Comment: This is untrue, updating system apps via ordinary APK's *does* work, provided that they are signed with the same key, they are essentially treated as overlays on /data overriding the originals on /system.  If the updated APK is uninstalled, the original built-in version in uncovered again.

Comment: Yes, provided they are built out of AOSP tree. Normally, when you install an app with inative libs, the system extracts them to a directory in /data partition and updates nativeLibraryPath (legacyNativeLibraryDir) accordingly. But system apks don't have their native libraries inside, so nativeLibraryPath would point to an empty directory.

Comment: Yeah I have gone for a pre-built APK. Yes I am doing some API changes and hence a new SDK  is required. So far I have been using the SDK (not within AOSP but the one generally we install in for android studio). But now with API change that wont work. Can you let me know how to build a new SDK?

Is this the right way?
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt

Also, I could not get point-3 completely. Could you please give an example or any reference where it is being done? And with this will APK upgrade will work?

Comment: Константин Осипов - I am looking for your valuable inputs :-)

Comment: Seems SDK building is disabled in the tailored AOSP we have for our products. So ignore this point.

But, could you please help in Point-3. Any example or reference? If we can disable stripping of libs from the .apk and still build the .apk as part of AOSP then it will be great for us.

Comment: @Aurovind_Sagar I'm implementing one right now. I'll share it as soon as it's ready.

Comment: @КонстантинОсипов, I am eagerly waiting :)

Comment: @Aurovind_Sagar I'm sorry for late response. I've succesfully tested the following solution: in core/install_jni_libs.mk you add +ifneq ($(filter keep_shared_libs tests samples, $(LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS)),)
my_embed_jni := true
endif   and in your application's Android.mk you add to LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS keep_shred_libs tag.

Comment: @Aurovind_Sagar Speaking of SDK, yes, this is the manual. I did use it myself, only for Linux.  I have never built SDK for Windows. However if you have a specific question, I may be able to answer it.

Comment: Thanks a ton @КонстантинОсипов ... I will try and let you know the results.